# Easing href to div/section of website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, frontend

I am not sure how to mimic this (http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/)
website's easing. What I mean by easing is when I click on the websites navigation tabs, I would slide to the appropriate portion of the `section/div`. I think it uses jQuery UI easing (http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/). I'm not sure where to start as I just start learning jQuery and front end development.

I think to get started, I would do

```js
$("#nav-pill").onclick(function() {
    // easing methods?
})
```

Comment: You may want to start off with something easier if you are new to jQuery. For instance, the code provided is not valid; it should be `$("#nav-pill").on('click', function() {});`. Then get into the animation features, then tackle something like this. This question is quite broad for SO.

Comment: What you're looking for is probably a jQuery scrollTo plugin. The easing is just the animation effect. http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Comment: I think it would be beneficial to start getting familiar with basic jQuery first before trying to replicate whole websites. This is a good place to start: http://learn.jquery.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error in your jQuery

```js
$("#nav-pill").on('click', function() { });
```

And the following code makes you achieve the smooth scrolling effect while

- **jQuery** code:

```
$("#nav-pill").on('click', function() {
    var mode="easeInOutCirc"; // or select the mode from jQuery easings
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
    }, 2000, mode);
});
```

It should work just fine for your case.

Comment: Right now I am able to move to the portion of the screen fine but I do not have the animation feature

Comment: I added jQueryUI CDN to my site but the other custom easing methods didnt work. Only the swing you provided me did =/

Answer (score 1):

For this effect you can use animate

Example:

```js
    $("#nav-pill").click(function(){
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
           scrollTop: $("#container").offset().top
        }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo'); 
     });
```

Or you can use ScrollTo plugin (http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)